# Exception thrown from ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice triggers error handler handler on Adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I set an advice on my `MessageHandler'

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outbound",adviceChain = "expressionAdvice")
public MessageHandler...
```

and configured it as:

```
@Bean
public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvicer expressionAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setFailureChannelName("failure");          
    return advice;
}
```

in `failure` handler I parse and detect the errors

```
 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "failure")
    public void handleFailures(Message<?> message)  {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException adviceException = (ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException) message.getPayload();
        Throwable cause = adviceException.getCause().getCause().getCause();
```

for specific errors I am doing some operations and flow is resumed.
But for specific error type I just log the error and continue,  for other types I am rethrowing exception to get a retry.

This works, but there is a side affect, this `throw Exception` triggers `ServiceActivator` that was set on `MessageProducerSupport.setErrorChannelName` on the adapter.

`@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "onerror")`

It does the job but I would like to avoid calling it, just to do the retries without going to this handler.

I do need this handler to catch other types of errors coming from source-channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this option on that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`:

```
/**
 * If true, any exception will be caught and null returned.
 * Default false.
 * @param trapException true to trap Exceptions.
 */
public void setTrapException(boolean trapException) {
```

More info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

**UPDATE**

For conditional exceptions "trapping", you need consider to implement a logic in your `failure` channel sub-flow. However `trapException` is still must be `true`.

This is the logic we have so far in the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`:

```
protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) {
    try {
        Object result = callback.execute();
        if (this.onSuccessExpression != null) {
            evaluateSuccessExpression(message);
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Exception actualException = unwrapExceptionIfNecessary(e);
        if (this.onFailureExpression != null) {
            Object evalResult = evaluateFailureExpression(message, actualException);
            if (this.returnFailureExpressionResult) {
                return evalResult;
            }
        }
        if (!this.trapException) {
            if (e instanceof ThrowableHolderException) { // NOSONAR
                throw (ThrowableHolderException) e;
            }
            else {
                throw new ThrowableHolderException(actualException); // NOSONAR lost stack trace
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, we catch an exception for a `callback.execute()` and process it in the `evaluateFailureExpression()` (which may just send an `ErrorMessage` to the mentioned `failureChannel`). Such a `this.messagingTemplate.send(this.failureChannel, errorMessage);` is not wrapped into a `try..catch`, so if you re-throw an exception from your error handling flow, it is going to be bubbled to the main flow.

Comment: but as I said for some scenarios I need exceptions for others I don't

Comment: Got it. Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: failure channel sub-flow in my case is the "handleFailures" `ServiceActivator`?

Comment: Yes, we can say that. But in proper term the flow is what includes channels in between and it doesn’t mean that only one channel and only one subscriber to it has to be in your error handling flow. You can have any complexity logic over there including filters , routers some external service calls